# how to get String value from EditText in Android?

Tags: android

I am using a dialog to get the string value from `edittext`, but it is not giving value of `editext`.

My code:

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id) 
        {
            case DIALOG_ALERT:
                // Create out AlterDialog

                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Search");
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
                builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null));
                Searchtxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_text);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Search", new OkOnClickListener());
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new CancelOnClickListener());
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
        }
                return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
    private final class OkOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {   
            //Implement search method here
            SearchText = Searchtxt.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(SearchText);
        }
    }
    private final class CancelOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

But it is giving error in line `SearchText = Searchtxt.getText().toString();`.

I need to pass string `searchText` further through Intent.

Log cat error:

```
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.web.dms.HomePage$OkOnClickListener.onClick(HomePage.java:155)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-09 15:18:55.634: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 15:18:57.044: I/Process(1847): Sending signal. PID: 1847 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is the exact error? can u post it here?

Comment: Show your Logcat @Shiva

Comment: Please check edited question with logcat

Comment: check and try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are finding view (EditText) from the main layout instead of inflated layout.

Try:

```
 View searchView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null);
 builder.setView(searchView);
 Searchtxt = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_text);
```

Comment: @Robin Why? Inflating search_dialog layout and how it can be a dialog with only EditText?

Comment: not working, I think this will not change EditText. and again same error in line SearchText = Searchtxt.getText().toString();

Comment: @shiva try full code given above. 100% guarantee it will work.

Comment: @shiva now how its working fine? And please remove all the comments above and clear the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
private final class OkOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

Try to use

```
private final class OkOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {   
            if(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE == which) {
                SearchText = ((EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.search_text)).getText().toString();
                System.out.println(SearchText);
                //Do your searching work 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: error in line SearchText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.search_text).getText().toString();

Comment: I have modified my post, try again?

Comment: just red line under findViewById

Comment: Seems some stupid code issue, please just move your cursor over it and see what hint is given by Eclipse.